# Is there any way to make this function faster

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

I am writing this function and first I was using loops. Loops takes time for I tried list comprehension. It didn't worked. There are 10 sec allowed for this function. Please check it. The function return sorted list of companies where their ratio is 5% or more.

```py
def mostActive(customers):
    # Write your code here
    tot = len(customers)
    set_cust = set(customers)
    cust_dict = {i: customers.count(i)/tot for i in set_cust}
    cus_list = [i for i in list(cust_dict) if cust_dict[i] >= 0.05]
    return sorted(cus_list)
```

#### Sample input and output

```
Omega
Alpha
Omega
Alpha
Omega
Alpha
Omega
Alpha
Omega
Alpha
Omega
Alpha
Omega
Alpha
Omega
Alpha
Omega
Alpha
Omega
Beta
```

Expected Output:

```
Alpha
Beta
Omega
```

Comment: and why not just use `collections.Counter`?

Comment: don't want to use any library, just pure python

Comment: then you should learn the Python Standard Library, because this IS part of Standard Library

Comment: As @buran said, `collections.Counter` is part of the standard library so it is pure python and it will handle.

Comment: ... it will handle your case better than implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line needs to be optimized:

```
cust_dict = {i: customers.count(i)/tot for i in set_cust}
```

It's quadratic in the number of customers, because `customers.count(i)` will iterate over the entire `customers` list for every customer in `set_cust`.

Instead, you can loop over `customers` once and keep track of counters in a dictionary, then divide by `tot` at the end.

Comment: I didn't know customerns.count() iterate over entire list.

Comment: @shahidhamdam if you have to count how many red balls you have in a bag of balls, do you think you are able to do it without seeing all the balls? Change red balls for `i` and all the balls for `customers`.

Comment: Creating a `dict` whose keys are the elements and whose values are the times each element appears is exactly a `collections.Counter` so you are basically reinventing the wheel. `collections.Counter` will be way more optimized that your version, is part of the standard library (pure python as you say) and allows for further improvements like using `most_common()` and breaking the first time you find one under 5% as every following element will also be under 5%, for example.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you can also use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

tot = len(customers)
[k for k, v in Counter(customers).items() if (v / tot >= 0.05)]
```

Comment: just pure python

Comment: Those are python in-built functions.

Comment: You are missing the sorted part, `Counter` has no ordering guarantee, does it?

Comment: @Adrilio - the OP sample output does not show the result in sorted order. If it matters I would use `Counter.most_common()` method and probably `itertools.takewhile`

Comment: @buran it does, it also mentions it in the question and has `sorted` in the provided code. Sorted by name, not by frequency.

Comment: @Adirio, `Beta` is present only once (5%) and is shown between `Alpha` (50%) and `Omega` (45%). i.e. their sample output is not sorted and contradicts the text of the question

Comment: @buran "Sorted by name, not by frequency."

Comment: @Adirio, yeah, you are right - it's in their code, but not explicitly specified in the question, I overlooked it.

Comment: @buran It is in the question too: "The function return **sorted** list of companies" (enphasis mine)

Comment: @Adirio, yes, but it does not specify sorted how. Given the case it feels more natural to need them sorted by frequency. That's why I was confused with the sample output.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, object-oriented approach:

```py
from collections import Counter


class FreqCounter(Counter):
    def most_common(self, *args, **kwargs):
        total = sum(self.values())
        return list(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1]/total), super().most_common(*args, **kwargs)))


def most_active(customers):
    most_active_customers = []
    for customer, freq in FreqCounter(customers).most_common():
        if freq < 0.05:
            break
        most_active_customers.append(customer)
    return sorted(most_active_customers)  # Remove sorted if needed in frequency order instead of name order


customers = [
    'Omega', 'Alpha', 'Omega', 'Alpha', 'Omega',
    'Alpha', 'Omega', 'Alpha', 'Omega', 'Alpha',
    'Omega', 'Alpha', 'Omega', 'Alpha', 'Omega',
    'Alpha', 'Omega', 'Alpha', 'Omega', 'Beta',
]
for customer in most_active(customers):
    print(customer)
```

Outputs:

```
Alpha
Beta
Omega
```

By removing the `sorted` as instructed, the output would be:

```
Omega
Alpha
Beta
```